# Local Workspaces Permissions Management and GitHub Integration

Tags: permissions, sudo, git, npm, visual-studio-code

I have a folder ~/workspaces where I place all my local repositories from GitHub and other coding projects.

I use VS Code and have had permissions problems since I installed Ubuntu a month ago. I receive the `EACCES: permission denied` in VS Code when I try to save files every single time after I did a `git checkout branch`. Is this normal?

I counter it with `$ sudo chown -R <user-name> <directory-name>` and `sudo chmod -R 777 .` (I do not really know whats the difference anyway) but it keeps coming up again.

Also, I thought doing `sudo npm i` is a bad thing but I keep getting `Access Denied Errors` for both local and global installations with npm if I do not sudo. How can I prevent this?

Finally, I would love to automatically login with GitHub via console without the need to constantly login with username and password. A quick Google could not find me a solution. How can I integrate an Access Token for the whole workspace folder (all repositories)? Is this possible?

Thank you very much for your support, it is much appreciated!

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS btw.

Comment: who owns `~/workspaces` (`ls -l ~/workspaces`), how do you launch vscode. And password aging can be used to prevent constant logins.

Comment: it's keep coming up because you keep writing to that location as root... which should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the credential helper so that Git will save your password in memory for some time. By default, Git will cache your password for 15 minutes.

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
# Set git to use the credential memory cache

git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
# Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds)
```

See: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/